# Why this simple htaccess code not working

Tags: wordpress, .htaccess, url-rewriting

I have Wordpress site where I have some custom URL not using Wordpress style

http://example.com/profile/xyz/
redirect to
http://example.com/c-profile/?c_id=xyz

Rule I have used in htaccess is as follow

```
RewriteRule ^/?profile/(.*)$ /c-profile/?c_id=$1 [QSD,L]
```

This is giving me 404 not found. Please help to fix this issue.

Answer (score 0):

If you [debug your htaccess code](https://htaccess.madewithlove.be) you can see what happens with the URL.

Your rule is

```
RewriteRule ^/?profile/(.*)$ /c-profile/?c_id=$1 [QSD,L]
```

...and this will rewrite `http://example.com/profile/xyz/` to `http://example.com/c-profile/`.

**Edit:**

The [[QSD] flag](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/trunk/rewrite/flags.html#flag_qsd) seems to discard your query string.

This rule will hopefully give you the correct URL:

```
RewriteRule ^/?profile/(.*?)/$ /c-profile/?c_id=$1 [L]
```

Comment: Can you pleas help me to correct it? I am quite new to htaccess

Comment: If I debug its showing proper result but in actual site am getting 404 :(  but if I access http://example.com/c-profile/?c_id=xyz it works properly

Comment: your answer is correct but now problem is site developed using wordpress with custom url and there its giving 404 any lead to fix this?

Comment: Is it working with other pretty URLs on your site? How is your permalink structure set in Wordpress?

Comment: rest all wordpress urls working fine... and permalink structure is http://romeromentoringcareers.com/2019/10/30/sample-post/  These are bit different url we want to give to our profiles...